# How to use the .AddMonths method of Get-Date in Powershell

Tags: powershell, date

I am writing a simple script that gets the date, gets the date 6 months from now, and copies both of those dates to the clipboard. When run, the script is supposed to copy:

`Terminated MM/dd/yy - Delete from AD on MM/dd/yyyy`
But it only copies
`Terminated MM/dd/yyyy - Delete from AD on`

```
$currentDate = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"
$futureDate = Get-Date.AddMonths(6) -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"
$copyThisText = "Terminated " + $currentDate + " - Delete from AD on " + $futureDate
$copyThisText | clip
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it failed is because once you format a date using `-Format "MM/dd/yyyy"` it converts that variable to a type of `string` rather than `datetime` which then means that the normal `datetime` methods are no longer available.

For demonstration purposes I have tried to change as little as possible. What I have done below is set the `$currentDate` and `$futureDate` without implicitly converting them to strings. I then format them the way you want when you are concatenating the strings in `$copyThisText`.

This will do what you want.

```
$currentDate = Get-Date
$futureDate = (Get-Date).AddMonths(6) 
$copyThisText = "Terminated " + $currentDate.tostring("MM/dd/yyyy") + " - Delete from AD on " + $futureDate.tostring("MM/dd/yyyy")
$copyThisText | clip
```

Furthermore there are multiple ways to format the strings that could aid in readability of the code. Thanks @Santiago Squarzon for the suggestion -

```
"Terminated {0:MM/dd/yyyy} - Delete from AD on {1:MM/dd/yyyy}" -f $currentDate, $futureDate
```

Comment: That is a very informative explanation! Thank you for your help. I would upvote but I don't have enough rep, sorry.

Comment: No worries, accepting the answer is more than enough!

Comment: Helpful, though note that the only problem with @HaydenHeffernan's code was this command: `Get-Date.AddMonths(6) -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"`, which could be fixed with: `Get-Date (Get-Date).AddMonths(6) -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"`. In other words: The problem was primarily one of syntax, not (premature) conversion to a string, given that both `$currentDate` and `$futureDate` are only used as _strings_.

Comment: Good spot but I think that, as a beginner, the code becomes unintuitive since ```get-date``` is called twice in the same command. Good suggestion though.